# Footer not sticking to end of the page

Tags: html, css

I have a page with header,content and footer. Issue i'm facing with the page is that after the footer there is a grey background which is being seen and the footer is not sticking to the end of the page.

I have uploaded my html here...
http://cruzer.net76.net/temp.html

Any help appreciated!

Comment: If you understand the part that's supposed to make it stick to the bottom of the page, why don't you include that in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in [Stylesheet](http://cruzer.net76.net/temp.css), set  `magin-top: 0` in line 300 (part of .wStoryFooterTxt's style);

Answer (score 0):

Remove `margin-top` inside `.wStoryFooterTxt` class in your CSS

Answer (score 0):

You height percentages are off. currently you have height for the header at 20%. `detailsContent` at 80% and the footer 40px;

Change the footer percentage to 20% and adjust the other and it should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in footer tag

```
#footer
{
    clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this css for footer div:

position:absolute;
bottom:0px;

This worked for me, hope it works for you also.